# Facebook Pixel not recording right events

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9, facebook-pixel

I have my facebook pixel installed on the webpage. Now I have the problem that it's tracking the wrong events on my website. Why is it monitoring all the events that I have on the same conversion. This is code:

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '981027905318896');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=981027905318896&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- DO NOT MODIFY -->
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

How can the event track this amount of Events:

[image]

I cannot find the mistake in the pixel to track in the magento backend. Where do I track the event? Where do I implement it in my code instead of the header in design of the configuration?

EDIT:

I've add the following snippet code for the pixel now on my site:

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code --> 
<script> !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod? n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n; n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0; t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'); 

fbq('init', '981027905318896'); 
fbq('track', "PageView"); 
fbq('track', 'AddToCart'); 
fbq('track', 'Search'); 
fbq('track', 'ViewContent'); 
fbq('track', 'InitiateCheckout'); 
fbq('track', 'AddToWishlist'); 
fbq('track', 'AddPaymentInfo'); 
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: '0.00', currency:'EUR'}); 
fbq('track', 'Lead'); 
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration'); 

</script> 
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=981027905318896&ev=PageView&noscript=1" /></noscript> 
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Comment: You can’t just add the same code for all pages, you need to track the specific events where they occur.

Comment: The problem is now that the top javascript is in the system. When I check out of the store with a small amount, I look at the code and there is no conversion code in there? 'Purchase' , {value etc should be in there then?

Comment: Your system needs to pass the correct parameter values of course.